# Referencing a variable from a different screen in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I need to reference the variable `name_input` in `TalkBot` screen. Here is the code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.2.1')
import pyttsx3
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FadeTransition
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel


class homeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwa):
        super().__init__(**kwa)

#bacgkround gradient
        bgbox = MDBoxLayout()
        bgbox.add_widget(Image(source='background.png', allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False, size_hint_y=1))
        self.add_widget(bgbox)

#page title
        topic = MDLabel(text="Personal Information", font_style="H4", pos_hint = {'x': 0.03, 'y': 0.45})
        topic_info = MDLabel(text="Please input the following information. This will be used to generate your report", font_style="H6", pos_hint = {'x':0.06, 'y':0.37})
#name input
        name_prompt = MDLabel(text="Name:", pos_hint = {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.3}, _text_color_str="white")
        name_input = TextInput(size_hint_x = 0.3, size_hint_y = 0.05, pos_hint = {'x':0.1, 'y': 0.73}, multiline = False)        #I want to reference this variable in talkbot screen

        self.add_widget(topic)
        self.add_widget(topic_info)
        self.add_widget(name_prompt)
        self.add_widget(name_input)


class TalkBot(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwa):
        super(TalkBot, self).__init__(**kwa)

        hs = self.manager.get_screen('homeScreen') #need to reference here but the error
        name = hs.name_input.text()         

        bgimg = Image(source="background.png", allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False, size_hint_y=1)
        self.add_widget(bgimg)

        def playvid(self):
            bgvid = Video(source="speechvid.avi", allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False, size_hint_y=1, state="play")
            box.add_widget(bgvid)

               
            engine=pyttsx3.init()
            engine.say(f"Hello {name}, welcome to Mind Magic!")
            print(name)
            engine.runAndWait()

        btn = MDRaisedButton(text="start", pos_hint={'x':0.49, 'y':0.49}, on_release=playvid)
        self.add_widget(btn)

        box=MDBoxLayout()
        self.add_widget(box)


class MindMagic(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        self._app_name = "MindMagic"
        self.icon = "logo.png"
        sm = ScreenManager(transition = FadeTransition())
        sm.add_widget(winvid(name="winvid"))
        sm.add_widget(homeScreen(name="homeScreen"))
        sm.add_widget(TalkBot(name="talkbot"))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MindMagic().run()
```

I have tried some solutions, and logically I think `self.manager.get_screen` should work. I have also tried `MDApp.get_running_app().root`. But both throw the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'`

Comment: Also, for some reason I can't change text colors of the labels? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kivy widget tree is not accessible at the time the objects get initialized. Your options are:

1. Move all operations that must acces the widget tree into a separate function and set it to execute on first render with `Clock.schedule_once`:

```
class TalkBot(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwa):
        super(TalkBot, self).__init__(**kwa)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.init)

    def init(self, _):
        hs = self.manager.get_screen('homeScreen')  # need to reference here but the error
        name = hs.name_input.text

        bgimg = Image(source="background.png", allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False, size_hint_y=1)
        self.add_widget(bgimg)

        def playvid(self):
            bgvid = Video(source="speechvid.avi", allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False, size_hint_y=1, state="play")
            box.add_widget(bgvid)

            engine = pyttsx3.init()
            engine.say(f"Hello {name}, welcome to Mind Magic!")
            print(name)
            engine.runAndWait()

        btn = MDRaisedButton(text="start", pos_hint={'x': 0.49, 'y': 0.49}, on_release=playvid)
        self.add_widget(btn)

        box = MDBoxLayout()
        self.add_widget(box)
```

(Note that this was still crashing for me at first because `name_input` is not assigned to an instance variable in `homeScreen` and because the TextInput's text is an attribute and not a callable and you were using `hs.name_input.text()`.)

2. Initialize TalkBot with `self.name = None`, then set it to the homeScreen's current value whenever you do the screen transition:

```
class homeScreen(Screen):
    ...
    def go_to_talkbot_screen(self):
        self.manager.get_screen("talkbot").name = self.name_input.text
        self.manager.current = "talkbot"
```

Comment: Oh, yea I forgot about the text being an attribute, sorry. I tried your first solution and it gives out the error `AttributeError: 'homeScreen' object has no attribute 'name_input'` so in the `homeScreen` I changed the variable to `self.name_input`. After this it seemed to work but, the pyttsx3 module didn't say the name, nor was it printed in terminal. It said the entire rest of the sentence but left out the `name` variable.

Comment: @Spaceyy64 well the thing is that the TextInput is empty at the time that you assign its text to the other variable. If you want it to update whenever something is inputted, you'd have to use the second solution or use a bind to update talkbot.name whenever the input changes (see the third example here https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#usage-example)

Comment: I just realised how basic this was.... ahh I need to train more, gonna pull up my training arc. Thx tho!

Comment: I used the `on_text` method mentioned in the link above, but still the `pyttsx3` engine doesn't say the `name_input`. I updated the original variables to `self.name_input` as otherwise it was throwing `AttributeError: 'homeScreen' object has no attribute 'name_input'`. What should I do?

Comment: Hey, I didn't really understand the 2nd solution you gave, could you please explain?

Comment: I assume you are transitioning from the home screen to the talkbot screen at some point in your code. You can assign the talkbot variable just before doing that.